# Reset timer every time the score increases

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, game-engine

I currently have this C# Code written for a game controller. I want to change the code , so the timer restarts every time the player scores. I cannot think of how to do it at the moment I'm sure its simple though! Please forgive the question I am a self taught coder and haven't gained all the knowledge yet. Thanks

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class GameController: MonoBehaviour {
 public BlockGenerator blockGenerator;
 public GameUI gameUI;
 public SoundController soundController;
 public bool playable;
 public float initTimer = 30 f;
 public bool gameOver = false;

 private int score;
 private int bestScore;
 private float timer;

 public float Timer {
  get {
   return timer;
  }
  set {
   timer = value;
   gameUI.UpdateTime();
  }
 }

 public int BestScore {
  get {
   return bestScore;
  }
 }

 public int Score {
  get {
   return score;
  }
  set {
   score = value;
   gameUI.UpdateScore();
  }
 }

 void Start() {
  playable = false;
  Timer = initTimer;
  Score = 0;
  bestScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BestScore", 0);
 }

 void Update() {
  if (playable) {
   if (timer > float.Epsilon) {
    Timer -= Time.deltaTime;
   } else {
    gameOver = true;
   }
  }


  if (gameOver) {
   GameOver();
   soundController.PlayGameOver();
   gameOver = false;
  }
 }

 public void GetScore() {
  Score += 1;
  blockGenerator.GenerateBlock();
  soundController.PlayBingo();

 }

 public void GameOver() {
  playable = false;
  SaveData();
  gameUI.GameOver();
 }

 public void Restart() {
  Score = 0;
  Timer = initTimer;
  playable = false;
  blockGenerator.BlockReset();
  blockGenerator.GenerateBlock();
  gameUI.Restart();
 }

 void SaveData() {
  if (bestScore < score) {
   bestScore = score;
   PlayerPrefs.SetInt("BestScore", bestScore);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `set { score = value; timer = 0; gameUI.UpdateScore(); }`

Comment: thank you @gusman for the simple solution that worked!

Comment: Setting the timer to 0 isn't a restart, surely? Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Option 1: Reset the timer in the GetScore method:

```
public void GetScore() {
  Score += 1;
  blockGenerator.GenerateBlock();
  soundController.PlayBingo();
  Timer = initTimer;
 }
```

Option 2: Reset the timer in the Score property setter:

```
    public int Score {
      get {
       return score;
      }
      set {
       score = value;
       Timer = initTimer;
       gameUI.UpdateScore();
      }
     }
```

If you go with option 2; you can also remove the following line from the Start method:

```
Timer = initTimer;
```

If the Score setter is called under any other circumstances then option 1 is the better option.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is Rate Limiting code. I originall wrote this up to be run in a Seperate thread, but you should be able to re-purpose it for your case:

```
integer interval = 20;
DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);

while(true){
  if(DateTime.Now >= dueTime){
    //insert code here

    //Update next dueTime
    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);
  }
  else{
    //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
}
```

You may have to move the setting for the "due time" to the main thread, wich may require some sycnhronization via lock().

Unfortuantely "Timer" is not a very clear description. By my last counting there are at least 5 different Timers in the .NET Framework, several unique to certain Display Technologies.

And since this is Unity this is likely game design, wich might have it's own approaches altogether.

Comment: This guy is a beginner. I suggest you rephrase your question so it can be understood without deeper knowledge of threading. And answering a Unity3D-related question with a general .NET-answer might not be the best way to go, either. Of course Unity3D has it's own timer...

Comment: I did not use a question format, at least no to my knowledge. With a game design you might not use a timer in the first place. I would usually count gameticks since the last action of that kind was triggered. basically make DueTime a gametick count that is polled every itteration of the Update Method/every game tick.

Comment: @Christoper My mistake, I meant to write "answer" instead of "question".

Comment: Unity3D has an integrated game time timer, wich can be easily used in the `OnUpdate()` or `OnFixedUpdate()` function.